# Multivariable chain rule $f(x,g(x))=0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

why is the derivative of $f(x,g(x))=0$  (by applying the chain rule) given by:$$0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,g(x))\cdot 1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider breaking up the function given by $h(x) = f(x,g(x))$ as
$$x \mapsto g(x) \mapsto (x,g(x)) \mapsto f(x,g(x)), $$
then applying the chain rule accordingly. If you feel confident enough, you could even synthesize the first two arrows into a single function.

**Edit:** [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329341/finding-an-expression-for-partial-j-partial-i-g-from-implicit-function-theor) of mine might also help.

Comment: So, when drawing a dependency graph, I could say that $f$ is depend on $x$ and $y$ while $y$ is dependent on $g(x)$?

Comment: You should see it this way: $h = f \circ \mathbf s$, where $\mathbf s : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $x \mapsto \mathbf s(x) = (x,g(x))$, and $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $(t_1,t_2) \mapsto f(t_1,t_2)$. Compute all possible derivatives of $\mathbf s$ and $f$, then the chain rule can be applied mechanically:
$$(f \circ \mathbf s)'(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t_1}(\mathbf s(x)) \frac{d s_1}{dx}(x) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial  t_2}(\mathbf s(x)) \frac{d s_2}{dx}(x). $$